# Python sort multiple lists, then print out same elements first

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three lists which contain different elements, however some of them are the same elements. Those same elements should be in the same order. Here is my code:

```
    import itertools
    a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    b = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
    c = [0, 4, 8, 12, 16]

    for x, y, z in itertools.zip_longest(a, b, c):
        print(x, y, z)
```

When I run it, prints out like so:

```
    0 0 0
    1 2 4
    2 4 8
    3 6 12
    4 8 16
    5 10 None
    6 12 None
    7 14 None
    8 None None
    9 None None
```

But I prefer them to become like this:

```
    0 0 0
    4 4 4
    8 8 8
    None 12 12
    2 2 None
    6 6 None
    1 10 16
    3 14 None
    5 None None
    7 None None
    9 None None
```

Edit: Those same elements should be on the top, 3 of them together. If there are 2 same elements out of 3, I'd like to have them like:

```
   
    None 12 12
```

as I indicated on the example above. If the elements are different on some particular line, it doesn't matter, leave them as it is (see the example: 1 10 16). 
To sum up; I need those same 3 elements first on the particular lines. Another tiny ideal example:

```
    a = [2, 1, 3, 5]
    b = [1, 2]
    c = [2, 3, 4]
```

our tiny example should become this:

```
    2 2 2
    3 None 3
    1 1 None
    5 None 4
```

Comment: I don't understand your sample output at all. Why is the middle column now full of Nones? Where did 15 go?

Comment: apprently I made a mistake while I wrote them. replace the 2nd with 3rd

Comment: If the question has a problem, [edit] it. You still haven't explained where 15 went. Explain your question much more clearly if you want help.

Comment: I just edited the question and tried to simplified it. Thanks for your interest @AlexHall

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
c = [0, 4, 8, 12, 16]

max_len = max(len(a),len(b),len(c))
print max_len

while not len(a)==int(max_len):
    a.append(0)


while not len(b)==int(max_len):
    b.append(0)

while not len(c)==int(max_len):
    c.append(0)

print a
print b
print c


d = [max(item) for item in zip(a,b,c)]

m = []
for item in d:
    if item in a:
        val1 = item
        a.remove(item)
    else: 
        val1 = None
    if item in b:
        val2 = item
        b.remove(item)
    else:
        val2 = None
    if item in c:
        val3 = item
        c.remove(item)
    else:
        val3 = None

    m.append((val1,val2,val3))

print m
```

**Output:**

```
10
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 0, 0]
[0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[(0, 0, 0), (4, 4, 4), (8, 8, 8), (None, 12, 12), (None, None, 16), (None, 10, None), (None, None, None), (None, 14, None), (None, None, None), (9, None, None)]
```